# How can one efficiently modify a collection within a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently typing this from my phone, so I don't have any code at hand. But I'll try to explain the situation.

Taking the example of a Recipe and Variations to this Recipe. The Recipe in this case holds a collection of Variations.

I have a Create view that takes the Recipe as the model.

I want this view to contain a list of Variations to the Recipe already. So there is an 'Add variation' button that opens a dialog with a partial view to add this variation.

Given that this is a yet non existing Recipe, I can't save the variation to the database yet, because it requires the RecipeId. So I think I am looking for a temporary place to store the new variations until I am saving the Recipe, and then also save the variations with it.

As MVC is stateless, I can't really save the variations anywhere temporarily, except for possibly the viewdata or tempdata, or I could add a bunch of hidden fields to the page via JavaScript, so that the Variation entries will be taken into the post triggered by saving the Recipe. All of which don't sound particularly tidy solutions.

What would be the most clean, ideal solution here?

Comment: When you open the dialog have it return json or an html view.  Those results will contain the newly added, selected variations.  Then when you save the recipe they will be posted along with the recipe itself for saving.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possible solutions:

1. Reconsider to use a wizard flow for creation instead - create recipe screen (no variations), then a chain of create variation screens. After that when you edit you can do it in the same page since the recipe is saved already.
2. As dreza mentionned, the variation partial view could return html to the creation page that adds the fields needed in the form for a full submit of the recipe + variations.
3. Pre-generate the RecipeId on the create form and reference to it for every actions, so you could save Variation (Id, RecipeId, ...) in the database before saving Recipe if you have different table/document. Then you lose the autogenerate id from SQL/Entity tho, and it's harder to maintain.
4. If you'd use a document database, you could have had the Recipe document have a list of VariationId and create the Variation on it's own without any direct reference to Recipe directly (No RecipeId in Variation). In SQL/Entity tho you would need 3 tables - Recipe (RecipeId), Variation (VariationId), RecipeVariation (RecipeId,VariationId) - it's uglier.

However, with complex, error prone UI like a parent + childs and such, another approach, and one I used extensively, is to create InputContexts associated to users and have InputModels are well as your normal models. These are semi-temporary models that exists until the user finishes to do his entry, they are usually used as ViewModels directly. For example, you could have:

```
public class InputContext
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string RouteName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class RecipeInput
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContextId { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class VariationInput
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContextId { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Your partial view that creates variation could simply save them to VariationInput with the current ContextId and that's it.

Then in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // We should check if one exists and reuse it instead, but omitted for clarity
    var context = new InputContext(GetUserId(), GetRouteName());
    db.Contexts.Add(context);
    db.Save(context);

    var model = new RecipeInput(context.Id);

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RecipeInput model)
{
    // Save the current input to DB
    db.RecipeInputs.Update(model);
    db.Save();

    // Do validation and return Create view on error...

    // load the context and related variations created
    var context = db.Contexts.Find(model.ContextId);
    var children = db.VariationInputs.Where(x => x.ContextId == context.Id).ToList();

    // Create the actual models from the input.
    var recipe = new Recipe();
    // set values from model

    foreach (var child in children )
    {
       var variation = new Variation();
       // set values from child

       recipe.Variations.Add(variation);
    }

    db.Recipes.Add(recipe);
    db.Save();

    // Cleanup if it worked
    db.RecipeInputs.Delete(model.Id);

    foreach (var child in children )
    {
       db.VariationInputs.Delete(child.Id);
    }

    // you could keep the Contexts as logs or delete them
    //...        
}
```

This is quite more complicated, but it can be used to save user data even between browser restart, session timeouts (they leave for lunch and come back and have to input everything again...), etc, and do some other neat tricks.

I usually store them in another database/partition/schema, and when I use SQL as a backend (because that's what the client wants), I often try use a Document Database (RavenDB or MongoDB for example) to store the context and input models as it is much nicer to play with in terms of MVC. This is not client data so it doesn't matter much.

If you need to see the list of variations in the Create Recipe page, you simply need to do have a partial view/ajax that gets a list of VariationInput in the current ContextId and display these.

Comment: I'll try to post an example of what I have later. I kind of see what you're aiming at. The wizard flow is a nice idea. But it doesn't really work in my exact application, as there's another scenario where variations are reusable, so to say. I appreciate your input, but I'll repost the question maybe in a different format. To get the right idea across.